# Dynamically tracing a route in real time using Google Maps API for Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am very new to Android development, and I am trying to create an app which will trace a route using a map overlay as I walk.  I have been able to get the map up and running, and can get it to show my movement, but I am lost as to how to show the route taken on the map.  I figure I need to use a polyline to do so, and I have tried to set up a List, and then to draw the line from that List, but I'm not sure if this is the appropriate logic to use.  Any help would definitely be appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far:

**ACTIVITY_MAIN_XML**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment  
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
      />
```

**MAINACTIVITY.JAVA**:

```
package com.example.google_maps_test;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener{

private OnLocationChangedListener mListener;
GoogleMap mMap;
LocationClient mLocationClient;
Location mCurrentLocation;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
List<LatLng>routePoints;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMap =((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this,this, this);
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(mLocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Location location = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    routePoints.add(latLng);
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17);
    mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mLocationClient.connect();
}

public void onStop(){
    mLocationClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}

public void deactivate(){
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if(mListener != null){
        mListener.onLocationChanged(location);
    }

    LatLng mapPoint = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    routePoints.add(mapPoint);
    Polyline route = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions());
    route.setPoints(routePoints);


}   
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

**ANDROIDMANIFEST_XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.google_maps_test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission     android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.google_maps_test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCOqSOYCyR-0bji10qcHa1WByfGoW-2ZsU"/>
</application>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

</manifest>
```

When I run this app, it crashes due to a Null Pointer Exception in the OnLocationChanged method.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Overall it sounds like you are on the right path. You fail to mention what object is causing the null pointer. It could be mMap or location for instance. Easier to help if you post LogCat dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this : It fixed an error at my application when trying to receive my location

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
            if (location != null)
            {
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            }
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who's wondering about the error, I find routePoints is never initialized.