# Track user location in Realtime using Polylines in Google Maps (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline, mapfragment, google-geolocation

I have some experience with Android, but am new to using the Google Maps API and Location Services. I am trying to show the user's movement on a MapFragment by moving the tracker and drawing a Polyline over where the user has been, sort of like MapMyRun.

From what I've seen on my debugger, I get a location after the Fragment resumes, and it is appended to the list of LatLngs. What I need is for the map to update every few seconds, or everytime the location changes by a tenth of a mile or so.

Here is what I have for the activity containing the MapFragment. My instinct tells me I need to do something inside of the the method handleNewLocation that would update the map...either that or perhaps do something in the LocationProvider that would update the location more often.

Any help, tips, or links would be greatly appreciated! My goal is to learn so that I understand how I can do this better in the future :)!

```
package com.seniorproject.trafton.trackrecordrace;

//Import statements not shown for readability
import...

public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  LocationProvider.LocationCallback {

public static final String TAG = "cloudsTraf";
        //MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

private LocationProvider mLocationProvider;

//variable for toggle buttons
private boolean isRunning = false;

//ArrayList to store geopoints for current run
private ArrayList<LatLng> geoPoints;

//Array of distances
private ArrayList<Float> distances;

//total distance
private float totalDistance;

//polyline that represented the route
Polyline tracker;

/*Load up widgets for tracking */
private ImageButton mPlayButton;
private ImageButton mPauseButton;

private TextView mRunTimeText;
private TextView mRunSpeedText;
private TextView mRunDistText;
private TextView mRunCalsText;

private Boolean mIsPlayButtonClicked;

//Handler to control timer tracking
//Thank you to Nikos Maravitsas for the tutorial on timers

private Handler timeHandler = new Handler();

private long startTime = 0L;
long timeInMillis = 0L;
long timeSwapBuffer = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    mLocationProvider = new LocationProvider(this, this);
    geoPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>(); //added

    //Add in code to inflate the tracking modules
    mRunTimeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.run_time_text);
    mRunDistText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.run_dist_text);
    mRunSpeedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.run_speed_text);

    Toolbar runToolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_run);
    runToolbar.setTitle("Run on " + getDate());
    runToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    setSupportActionBar(runToolbar);

}

//Inflate the menu for the toolbar
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.e("XXX", "Menu created");
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_maps_run, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

//Handles possibilities of menu items being selected.
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_begin_run:
            if (!isRunning) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                timeHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread,0);
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_24dp);
                isRunning = true;
            }
            else {
                timeSwapBuffer += timeInMillis;
                timeHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_24dp);
                isRunning = false;

            }
            return true;

        case R.id.action_stop_run:
            //stop run, save run, and transport user to the stats for that run

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/*Code to update the timer, begins a new timer thread.*/
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        timeInMillis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        updatedTime = timeSwapBuffer + timeInMillis;

        //Get integer value from time update and put into textView
        int seconds = (int) (updatedTime/1000);
        //need two seconds variables for formatting purposes.
        int secs = seconds % 60;
        int mins = (seconds / 60);
        int hours = (mins / 60);

        mRunTimeText.setText("" + hours + ":" +
                String.format("%02d", mins) + ":" +
                String.format("%02d", secs));
        timeHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

};

/* */

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mLocationProvider.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mLocationProvider.disconnect();
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p/>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 * <p/>
 * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
 * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
 * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
 * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() {
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}

//handle new location
public void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

    //Get the new geopoints to redraw the line on each iteration
    geoPoints.add(latLng);
    //get the latest distance update
    if (geoPoints.size() > 2) {
        calculateDistance();
    }
    //set the distance test
    mRunDistText.setText(Float.toString(totalDistance) + " Meters");
    mRunSpeedText.setText((location.getSpeed() + " m/s"));

    //draw the polyline
    drawRoute();
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("I am here!");
    mMap.addMarker(options);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15));
}

/*
*Methods to calculate metrics. All measurements returned are approximations.
 */
//returns the latest distance between geoPoints. Append to total number
public void calculateDistance(){
    Location newLoc = new Location("Latest Location");
    Location oldLoc = new Location("Last known Location");
    LatLng newPt = geoPoints.get(geoPoints.size()- 1);
    LatLng oldPt = geoPoints.get(geoPoints.size()-2);
    distances.add(oldLoc.distanceTo(newLoc));
    //add to the distance variable
    totalDistance = totalDistance + oldLoc.distanceTo(newLoc);
    Log.d(TAG, "distance between points is: " + oldLoc.distanceTo(newLoc));
}

//calculates the current KCals being burned
public void calculateKcals(){

}

//get today's date in a simple format
public String getDate(){
    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
    String todaysDate = formatter.format(today);
    return todaysDate;
}

//method to draw polyline. Uses the recorded geopoints.
public void drawRoute(){
    mMap.clear();
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark).geodesic(true).visible(true);
    for(int i = 0; i < geoPoints.size(); i++){
        LatLng pt = geoPoints.get(i);
        options.add(pt);
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"GeoPoints recorded: " + geoPoints);
    mMap.addPolyline(options);
}
```

}

I'm grabbing the location in a different file (Because, y'know, modularity is good.).
If there is any additional data I can provide, I would be more than happy to include it!

```
package com.seniorproject.trafton.trackrecordrace;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;


public class LocationProvider implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

public abstract interface LocationCallback {
    public void handleNewLocation(Location location);
}

public static final String TAG = LocationProvider.class.getSimpleName();

/*
 * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
 * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
 */
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
private Context mContext;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;


public LocationProvider(Context context, LocationCallback callback) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    mLocationCallback = callback;

    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(3 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

    mContext = context;
}

public void connect() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

public void disconnect() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Location services connected.");

    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
    else {
        mLocationCallback.handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    /*
     * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
     * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
     * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
     * error.
     */
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution() && mContext instanceof Activity) {
        try {
            Activity activity = (Activity)mContext;
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(activity, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
        /*
         * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
         * PendingIntent
         */
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Log the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        /*
         * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
         * user with the error.
         */
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLocationCallback.handleNewLocation(location);
    Log.i(TAG, "New location received ");
}
```

}

Comment: Try to read this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407929/dynamically-tracing-a-route-in-real-time-using-google-maps-api-for-android). This is a possible duplicate of your question.

Answer (score 0):

To draw a Polyline on the map do this in onLocationChanged

```
Polyline route = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions());
route.setPoints(mGeoPoints);`
```